# CASE WHEN with OR

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-when

there is a way to use OR with CASE WHEN, like this?

```
SELECT
    case 'brasil'   
    when 'chile' OR 'brasil' THEN   
                        'ok'
    when 'argentina' then
        'ok2'
    when 'venezuela' THEN
        'ok3'
    ELSE
        'chaves'
end;
```

Comment: A constant in the case part (`case 'brasil'`) doesn't make sense and isn't valid in the first place. If it _was_ valid SQL, it wouldn't make sense as you can replace that with a simple `select 'ok'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are thinking about it correctly. You can use OR or IN with your select..case statement:

```
select

  case
  -- one way or writing OR
  when country = 'brasil' or country = 'chile' then '....'
  -- another way of writing OR
  when country in ('china', 'japan') then '...'
  else '..'
  end

from tablename;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c1cef/2

Comment: Just note that in this instance you're not using the simplified version of the `CASE` statement with `CASE <expression> WHEN...`

Comment: I've removed the description of PL/pgSQL since it can be misleading to the OP. Thank you for bringing it to attention.

Comment: You can shorten the `when` expression using `in`:  `case when country in ('brasil', 'chile') then ...`